# Is there way to change set of variables that gradient is computed on training loop?

Tags: tensorflow

I’m making denoising auto encoder.
Because my denoising auto encoder is very large, I want to reduce computation about gradient.

According to [1], it seem to good idea that only some rows randomly chosen from weight matrix  are updated.

TensorFlow has basic mechanism to restrict gradient computation to specific variables.
 For example AdamOptimizer(var_list=[w1, w2]).minimize().
In this case, gradients are computed about w1 and w2 .
 But this procedure adds new operation to computation graph whenever this method is called.
Therefore this mechanism can not be used this purpose (I think if that method is called on training loop, memory usage goes on increasing).

Can I update var_list in AdamOptimizer on training loop? 
Is there other method to change set of variables that gradient is computed on training loop?

[1] http://www.icml-2011.org/papers/491_icmlpaper.pdf